# Eclipse opens some .c files incorrectly

Tags: eclipse

I'm using a version of Eclipse that came zipped in a folder so I didn't have to install it, it's running in Ubuntu and the project in question is in C and was not created by me.

Most files open correctly, but a few of them are opened in a window with two columns of line numbers and slightly different syntax colours than normal *.c files (here's a screen-shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ4Fy.jpg). The icon visible in the tab is also different (looks like a text file icon).

Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: did you check the (General/Editors) File Associations under Preferences to see if anything looked off?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong, but I'm not experienced with Eclipse. As I said, most files are working fine, this is only happening with a few of them.

Comment: If you right click on the file in the Project Explorer (etc.) you should have an Open With option that you can use to figure out what Editor is being used.  Determining if the wrong editor is sometimes being opened and what that Editor is will help provide more information on the issue.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Eclipse is opening the file with the 'C Editor', whilst apparently the desired option is 'C/C++ Editor'. I will try and play around with the settings and reply if I manage to fix the problem.